# Can I modify MVC viewmodel before passing it into a Partial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

If I have a model passed onto Index.cshtml

Can I modify a property on the model inside of a code block in Index.cshtml and then pass modified model into Html.Partial("_MyView", Model)

```
@model.Name = "Joe"

@Html.Partial("_MyView", Model)

@model.Name = "Ann"

@Html.Partial("_MyView", Model)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can; you just need to use the `Model` property, not the `@model` directive.

```
@{ Model.Name = "Joe" }

@Html.Partial("_MyView", Model)

@{ Model.Name = "Ann" }

@Html.Partial("_MyView", Model)
```

Comment: Also, be aware that there is no guarantee that your code will be executed in the order it's listed in the cshtml file.  It will likely be executed in that order, but AFAIK there is no guarantee that a future version may not try and optimize the way it does things.

Comment: I was thinking that already things might be done that way for optimisation, which is why I asked. Thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

You could modified the value of property in model to use further in your view but before render. one it is rendered value cant be modified needed server side interaction,
you can set value as

```
<% Model.Address="none" ;%>
<%: Model.Address %>
```